# Cocoapods: OS X test app in iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have an iOS app that we'll call **Potato**. It has an command line OS X utility called **PotatoServiceTest** in a PotatoServiceTest subdirectory. Both of these use (currently) a single pod, **AFNetworking**.

In the past, I'd just use a AFNetworking git submodule from both. But I'd really like to give Cocoapods a try here. How do I configure my Podfile?

My Podfile currently looks like this:

```
xcodeproj 'Potato.xcodeproj'
target 'Potato' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

My understanding is that this should be what I need:

```
xcodeproj 'Potato.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'PotatoServiceTest/PotatoServiceTest.xcodeproj'

target 'Potato' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'PotatoServiceTest' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

However, I get an error:

```
[!] Unable to find a target named `Potato`
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current Podfile (the one with only one `xcodeproj` directive) is fine. Run `pod install` and a new Potato workspace will be created (`Potato.xcworkspace`). Then you just have to add `PotatoServiceTest.xcodeproj` in your Potato workspace and AFNetworking will be available to your PotatoServiceTest target too.

Comment: That's giving me the "unable to find a target named Potato" error I mentioned above. Am I trying to do too much too quickly here?

Comment: Oh, wait. I think I misinterpreted "current." :)

Comment: Not described here is combining the target CLI app into the main project, but this was the approach I ended up taking. Thanks. :)